# React native disable submit keyboard on device if text input is empty string

Tags: react-native

Like a title, I want to disable a submit button (Search) on device's keyboard if text input is an empty string.
I creating a search bar and using TextInput.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

you should have 2 state (textSearch and buttonStatus) and check every `onChangeText` in `TextInput` props

here's a simple code I've used:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import RN, {View, StyleSheet, Text} from 'react-native';

export default class History extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      search:null,
      disabledButton:true
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <RN.TextInput
          value={this.state.search}
          onChangeText={(e)=>{
            this.setState({search:e, disabledButton:e==""?true:false})
          }}
        />
        <RN.Button
          title="Search"
          disabled={this.state.disabledButton}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{flex:1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}
})
```

Comment: in TextInput we have `onSubmitEditing`, and I want disable it if text input is empty string.

Comment: it's not a good UX to disable it, showing alert is better than disabling it thought

Comment: @ninh_nguyen if you need only on iOS you should check [enablesReturnKeyAutomatically](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#enablesreturnkeyautomatically)

Answer (score 0):

this is the first time I've provided help here, so hopefully it helps someone.

The inputText should be whatever state you use to store your text.

addItem() is whatever function name you want to execute when there are enough characters.

I wanted to require the user to type more than 1 character, so adjust to your liking.

**onSubmitEditing={() => {(inputText.length < 2) ? console.log('test') : addItem()}}**

```
<TextInput
    style={styles.input}
    onSubmitEditing={() => {
        (inputText.length < 2) ? console.log('test') : addItem()
    }}
    maxLength={20}
    autoCorrect={false}
    onChangeText={onChangeText}
    placeholder={'Scavenger Hunt Item'}
    value={inputText}>
</TextInput>
```